# Command-hover tooltip in VSCode VIM without using mouse

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I recently discovered that there is an expanded hover tooltip in VSCode vim that can be seen by hovering over a token while holding the command key.  In my case I'm particularly interested in seeing typescript type definitions that are available in this tooltip, but not in the basic hover tooltip.

I use the VSCode Vim extension, so use 'gh' to trigger these tooltips without using a mouse, but holding command+'gh' doesn't produce the desired effect (it triggers other command modifier hotkeys).

This is an example of the tooltip that loads from 'gh':

[image: Hover without command]

This is an example of the expanded tooltip from holding command while hovering:

[image: Hover with command]

Comment: Just learned the `gh` thing, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

I believe this expanded hover is the VS Code command ID `editor.action.showDefinitionPreviewHover`. There is no binding for this built in to VSCodeVim as of this writing, so you can define your own in your settings:

```js
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
  {
    "before": ["g", "H"],
    "commands": [{ "command": "editor.action.showDefinitionPreviewHover" }]
  }
]
```

Comment: For me this shows the preview, but then I can no longer navigate unless I press escape.

Comment: I think it solution is not perfect cause you can't roll in the hover and you can't use mouse to roll it as well(the hover will disappear).